# Is there anything stopping me from checking into my flight twice?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, check-in

When I'm busy, checking in to my flights via the web is often convenient. I get my boarding passes sent right to my phone and I don't **need** to worry about printing them before arriving to the airport. However, I also like collecting physical copies of my boarding passes. They're cool momentos of my travels more than anything else, and when I get the chance to print them out, I typically do.

My question is, if I've already checked into my flight on my phone, can I print another set of boarding passes at the airport? I do like the official airport paper ones most.

To make this question more general, consider the unfortunate situation of your phone dying. Having a backup physical copy of your boarding pass could save the day.

In essence, is there anything stopping me from making another boarding pass at the kiosk after I've checked in beforehand?

Comment: This wouldn't be checking in twice, this would just be reprinting the boarding pass, which can be done

Comment: Although with low cost airlines the situation might be a bit different (usually they charge a fee for airport checkin or even for printing boarding passes at the counter).

Comment: As @dunni said, budget airlines usually try to screw you over with additional fees to print. A couple of years ago I had to rush around the airport to print tickets because RyanAir didn't feel like printing them at Faro (PT). Any respectable airline would gladly do this for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some airlines even enable you to "check-in" multiple times online or in their mobile app, and give you the option of changing your seat each time you do.

Subsequent "check-ins" after the first one are really just updates of your check-in. If you look at your boarding pass, there's usually a "sequence number" (often marked `SEQ`, but sometimes just a 3-digit number) which shows your rank in the check-in order, and this won't change.

Getting a printed boarding pass at a kiosk or desk is quite common, even if you checked in online. It is extremely common if you have bags. Some airlines will now try to cut on the waste and avoid printing a boarding pass if you have already checked-in (unless you ask), but many still do, especially as it makes it easier to put the luggage sticker stubs somewhere useful.

Some of the low-cost airlines may be a bit more tricky, as they may want to charge you for checking in at the airport or printing a boarding pass, sometimes outrageous amounts, but I have yet to see an incumbent that will have an issue.

Answer (score 19):

Have done this so many times, with many, many airlines.  I often check in online in case I'm delayed by traffic etc, at least I've bought myself some time - but if I get there on time, I too like to get the actual boarding pass.

Also for 18 months I worked for an airline in Australia, had to fly regularly and we'd regularly reprint, change, update and cancel boarding passes - outside at check in, at the service desk, and even at the gate, depending on the situation.

Comment: I've also do it usually, because the image on the phone sometimes can't be read by the gate scanner.

Comment: @WGroleau in that case showing your passport should be enough - no need to waste paper.

Comment: I’m skeptical.  Anyone else ever get down the jetway or even past TSA with no scannable boarding pass?

Comment: @WGroleau I suspect he means at the gate - show your passport, and they can reprint. You DO need a boarding pass to get on the plane tho, as the on-plane crew need to double check your seat, that you're on the correct flight ,and  to confirm you entered the plane.

Comment: Well, in most airports, you have a “passengers only” sign before you get to a gate or even an “empty your pockets for security” line.

Comment: @WGroleau sometimes. In Christchurch with regional flights, you can walk right up to the gate staff without going through security. In Australia, you don't need to present any evidence of a flight before going through security (staff at my old work would go through at the airport just to get some lunch from the restaurants within)

Answer (score 8):

No, but it is not considered as a double checkin. You have the same seat and the same sequence number. You only print your boarding pass twice.

Answer (score 2):

No.  I do this all the time.  Reissuing boarding passes is routine; they're easy to lose, after all.

Comment: And the airlines are happy to give you another opportunity to pay for more checked baggage or an upgraded seat.